# NUnit Test Adapter перестает открывать тесты, после нескольких запусков тестов

Tags: юнит-тесты, visual-studio-2015, nunit

Я использую NUnit framework v3.12.0 и NUnit3TestAdapter v3.16.1 в VS2015.

Пытаюсь запустить тесты, несколько запусков все работает нормально. Однако затем тесты пропадают, а в Output выводится следующее сообщение:
[image: в Output выводится следующее сообщение:]

> An exception occurred while test discoverer 'NUnit3TestDiscoverer' was loading tests. Exception: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

После перезапуска VS2015 тесты снова появляются, однако затем после нескольких запусков тестов все снова повторяется.

Что я пробовал

1. Перезапуск VS и перегрузка компа
2. Очистка и ребилд решения
3. Удаление кэша VS а именно папку Temp/VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions
4. Переустановка пакетов NUnit framework v3.12.0 и NUnit3TestAdapter v3.16.1

Нашел аналогичный вопрос в англоязычном Stack Overflow [Nunit Test Adapter not discovering tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490203/nunit-test-adapter-not-discovering-tests)
, но ответов там нет :(.

Нашел похожий вопрос в [How to fix Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.engine, Version=3.7.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526149/how-to-fix-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-nunit-engine-version-3-7-0-0), но приведенное там решение не работает.

Список установленных пакетов в проекте
[image: Список установленных пакетов в проекте]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помог переход на Visual Studio 2019 там тесты проходят нормально.

Полное удаление и перестановка Visual Studio c использование утилиты VisualStudioUninstaller не помогло.
Это довольно странно, почему-то даже переустановка Windows 10 и Visual Studio не помогла.